# Extract string part from text in r

Tags: r

I have text string such like this: `Stoli 2.0 Intel PAV UMA, Phelps 1.0 Intel PAV_BayTrail x360` and I need to extract only the part Stoli 2.0 from the first one and Phelps 1.0 from the second one.

Could you anyone give me some sufficient solutio, how to do that, please? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `gsub` function to do what you need:

```
> x <- c("Stoli 2.0 Intel PAV UMA", "Phelps 1.0 Intel PAV_BayTrail x360")
> gsub("(^.* [0-9]*\\.[0-9]*).*", "\\1", x, perl = T, )
[1] "Stoli 2.0"  "Phelps 1.0"
```